# Avoid light when allowing access to webcam using Flash

Tags: flash, webcam

Is there any way to avoid seeing the light of the camera when the user clicks on the allow button of the "security settings" of the flash client. We need to start in audio only but when allowing access to the microphone the light of the camera goes on for a second before we can switch to audio only.

We also want the user to be able to click allow and have the camera off (and light off) till we want to turn it on around 15 seconds later.

Comment: What do you mean by the light? This green dot NEAR the camera indicating that it is recorsing stuff at the moment?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to turn it off when I allow the flash component, because if the people chose audio, they feel weird when they see the green light of the web cam activated. They feel like the camera is recording.